C++ library for symbolic differentiation of polish and reverse Polish notation expressions
I am looking for a C++ library that allows the user to pass in a prefix or postfix expression string or list as input that returns the derivative wrt some operand in the same notation as the input expression. So far all the libraries I could find only support infix expressions like Ev3. Is there such a library that natively supports this, or something that can be minimally engineered to do so?

Apparently I forgot there was this paper that did this for reverse polish notation (postfix) which I'd started putting into one program here. So far I haven't found any bugs, but I'll keep checking and adding support for more functions and then figure out how to do it for polish notation (prefix).
